# Connect with PayPal in PHP for user authentication

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to implement a "Connect with PayPal" button on my website using PHP and CURL.
I already managed to receive an auth code and with this code an access token, but I'm not able to receive the user data. My REST app is approved and I should be able to get the user email.
I don't want to use the PayPal PHP SDK because is now deprecated.

Here is my code:

```
$pp_client_id = {my client id};
$pp_secret = {my secret};

$code = $_GET['code'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $pp_client_id.':'.$pp_secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
   'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
   'code'=> $code
)));

$res_authcode = curl_exec($ch);

if (empty($res_authcode)) {
   // print error
} else {
   $json_authcode = json_decode($res_authcode);
   $refresh_token = $json_authcode->refresh_token;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
      'grant_type'=>'refresh_token',
      'refresh_token'=> $refresh_token
   )));

   $res_token = curl_exec($ch);

   if(empty($res_token)) {
      // print error
   } else {
     $json_token = json_decode($res_token);
     $access_token = $json_authcode->access_token;

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/userinfo/?schema=paypalv1.1');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
       'access_token'=> $access_token
     )));

     $res_userinfo = curl_exec($ch);
 
     if(empty($res_userinfo)) {
       // print error
     } else {
       $json_userinfo = json_decode($res_userinfo);
       print_r($json_userinfo);
     }
   }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I'm getting a RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND message. What should I change on my code to get the user info?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)? It handles a lot of the nasty for you, so issues like these don't come up (as often lol).

Comment: @IncredibleHat thanks for the typo advice. I don't want to use the SDK because it's deprecated

Comment: Anyhoo, the longhang method, I think your URL is wrong... try `https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo` for the second call.

Comment: Nevermind the PHP REST SDK I mentioned... that was for orders/payments... not Sign In With PayPal (which only works from the older depreciated SDK).

Comment: I just managed to solve the problem changing the code! Do you think I should delete my question or should I let it with my answer here?

Comment: If it wasnt just a typo, then you could post the answer, as PayPal related questions/answers are far n few between ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve my problem and receive the user info from PayPal via cURL.

I changed the connection URL and headers to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/userinfo?schema=openid');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
  'content-type: application/json'
));

$res_userinfo = curl_exec($ch);
```